# load base64 image with fabric.Image.fromURL

Tags: backbone.js, base64, fabricjs

I am working with `fabric.js` inside of `backbone.js`, and trying to figure out how to load a Base64 image using `fabric`'s command:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL( 'url', function(img)....
```

It works fine when I plug in a static url, like:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.domain.com/image.jpg', function(img) {
    img.set({ left: ui.offset.left, top: ui.offset.top});
    canvas.add(img);       
});
```

but I cannot get a Base64 image to load successfully. How I am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: post the dataurl you are using

Comment: works fine for me sending a `base64` like this: `data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJosM//AwO/AwHVYZ/z595kz....`. I'm using `custom fabric build` generated from here http://fabricjs.com/build/. But i'm searching another option because i need make that works in offline mode and apparently `fabric.Image.fromURL`  works only in online mode.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above answers are correct. But without an example, the answers aren't obvious.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo....', function(img) {
    img.set({ left: ui.offset.left, top: ui.offset.top});
    canvas.add(img);       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: `data:image/jpeg;base64,"+url`. If this doesn't work then maybe your `base64` is broken or you might need to tweak the `base64` to `unit8` conversion technique provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/1309352) and add the image [data](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_imagedata_data.asp) to the image object placed inside the canvas.

[Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your data url is according to the following format:

> data:[< mediatype >][;base64],< data >

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

`<data>` above should be a valid *base64* string.

If you want to test whether it's fabric that's not rendering the url or url isn't correct, try to open the whole data url in browser, browser will render the image if it's a correct data url.

fabric should just work fine for a *base64* data url as it works for *http* image address.